# How to retrieve all equations in word document using DocX library

Tags: c#, docx, novacode-docx

I am using the [DocX library](https://docx.codeplex.com) to post-process my documents.

Is there a way to get a list of  all equations in the document?

I have seen that you can easily insert an equation using `DocX.InsertEquation()`, however I can't find a way to retrieve a list of all equations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using the following LINQ expression:

```
string mathNamespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math";
var equations = doc.Paragraphs.Where(
                    p => p.Xml.Descendants(XName.Get("oMathPara",mathNamespace)).Any());
```

All equations are wrapped in the paragraph element, but they also contain a special XML element which is called `oMathPara` helping to identify them.